# count # of times a text appears in a str

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to search this `string(TenderString1)` for `SPT`. This just outputs the number of characters - so if there were 1 `SPT` in this string it would return 3 (number of characters).  So I am attempting to divide the result by the length of `SPT` (3) to get the number of occurrences of `SPT` in the string but it is not returning the correct number
`(LEN(TenderString1) - LEN(REPLACE(TenderString1, 'SPT', '')) / len('SPT'))`Test

TenderString1 Column:

```
UAD,MTY,CL,CLTG,OFD,OFD,SPT,SL
```

Answer should be: 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of times a substring appears in a string when you have something delimited like you do, something like this would do it:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(',UAD,MTY,CL,CLTG,OFD,OFD,SPT,SL,SPT,SPT', ',') WHERE value='SPT'
```

This one returns a 3.

And here's it is with some data:

```
SELECT
VAL, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(VAL, ',')  WHERE value='SPT') CNT
FROM
(
SELECT ',UAD,MTY,CL,CLTG,OFD,OFD,SPT,SL,SPT,SPT' AS VAL
UNION
SELECT ',UAD,MTY,CL,CLTG,OFD,OFD,SPT,SL,SPT,SPT,SPT' AS VAL
) A
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! - Although I am not sure this is what I was looking for. Being that I have a large data set, typing out these select statements for each occurrence wouldn't be possible

Comment: @DrewMurray - you wouldn't...in those parenthesis where the union is, you would instead put your select to your database table...mine is just an example...select tenderstring1 from (table)...whatever your name of your table is

Comment: Roger that - thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @DrewMurray you will also notice in STRING_SPLIT i reference VAL, because that's my column name in the parenthesis...that will differ for you too

Comment: Apologies - but I am still learning. This is what I modified to:                                            ,(Select
TenderString1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(TenderString1, ',')  WHERE value='SPT') CNT
FROM
Cte2) Test2                   I received this message: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS." @Ctznkane525

Comment: Show the whole query...you have a two columns as a column...the string and the count...something isn't right...your nested column tests should only have the count...tenderstring1 would be a duffer column in your query altogether based on what I think you are doing

Answer (score 0):

The division is of [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql) than subtraction, your code executes LEN(REPLACE(TenderString1, 'SPT', '')) / len('SPT') first and then the result is subtracted from LEN(TenderString1). You could use parenthesis to perform the subtraction first and then divide the result by len('STR')..pay attention that LEN() ignores trailing spaces, so better to prevent wrong calculations (when the searched term is at the end of the string/value) by appending another character at the end of the column value/string.

```
select TenderString1,
    (LEN(TenderString1) - LEN(REPLACE(TenderString1, 'SPT', '')) / len('SPT')) as Test,
    (LEN(TenderString1) - LEN(REPLACE(TenderString1, 'SPT', ''))) / len('SPT') as Test1,
    (LEN(TenderString1+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderString1+'.', 'SPT', ''))) / len('SPT') as SPToccurence
from 
(values
(',UAD,MTY,CL,CLTG,OFD,OFD,SPT,SL'),
(',UAD,MTY,CL,CLTG,OFD,OFD,SL,          SPT')
) as t(TenderString1);
```

Comment: Regarding the "From", would this be where I would input the table name? @lptr